Was the serpent an animal or the devil?
Why do most Christians believe that the serpent was the devil himself directly appearing to Eve  when scripture explicitly states that it was a literal snake and in this I quote the following   verses to back up my claim
Genesis 3:15

I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between your offspring and her offspring; he shall bruise your head, and you shall bruise his heel.”

Only a created animal can have an offspring and not a spirit angel like the devil.
Genesis 3:14

Because you have done this, cursed are you above all livestock and above all beasts of the field; on your belly you shall go, and dust you shall eat all the days of your life.

The serpent is cursed above all animals and he is cursed to crawl because he was created with legs before he was possessed. Now the Bible says this was a visible creature that Eve could see and interact with, why do most people think the serpent was the devil himself who was in spirit form and invisible to Eve?
An angel possessed a donkey in the Balaam story and the donkey talked back, why is it hard to believe this was the case in the garden?

People are going to approach Genesis from a wide variety of perspectives. Some may view as strictly literal, others as purely symbolic, and still others as stitched together folk tales. That said, there are biblical passages that directly identify satan as "the serpent of old" (Revelation 12:9; 20:2). Furthermore, symbolically the snake is a tempter - luring people away from God and into sin and destruction; which is very easy to associate with satan.

@RyanPierceWilliams, let's just stick to the Bible in this case, read the curses God uttered to the serpent , the serpent will bite the foot of man and man will hit it on the head which is the practice to date when people see snakes. The serpent is an animal as per the Genesis stories of creation because the devil was in  spirit form , invisible to Adam and Eve

You ignored what @RyanPierceWilliams stated. So I will state it again . - Revelation 12:9 and 20:2 (we are 'sticking to the Bible') both identify Serpent as being the same Entity as Satan. It is your opinion that a literal snake spoke to Eve.  Whereas God has promised that a seed of Eve will ascend above the serpent and bruise its head. Which some believe is accomplished in the ascension of Jesus Christ above all principality and power. See the answer to a similar question Why is the serpent believed to be literal by many ?

Only a created animal can have an offspring and not a spirit angel like the devil. But Jesus said 'Ye are of your father, the Devil', John 8:44. Again, you state an opinion which is not what we see if we 'stick to the Bible'.

@Nigel, the devil cannot bring forth an offspring, you have to understand that God is addressing creatures here whom He creates with the power to procreate, the serpent included and that's why snakes and human beings have reproduced since the beginning up to now even up to the return

Looks to me as if you have just contradicted Jesus of Nazareth (the devil cannot bring forth an offspring - sic). Again, you have paid no attention when a scripture is provided you. No further comment.Thank you.

@NigelJ, when Jesus told the Jews they are of their father the devil he didn't mean the devil biologically gave birth to the Jews , he said so because they did his will contrary to the will of God, of course those Jews had their fathers who were flesh and blood

So, you are suggesting that Jesus did not speak 'literally' on that particular occasion . . . . . . . . I see.

@NigelJ, yes so thats my point, the devil cannot sire children,  even the angels he leads , he didn't create any of them. My point is that this being might have possessed that innocent animal which interacted with Eve. If an angel in the Balaam story caused a donkey to speak why not Lucifer causing a serpent to speak to lie to the woman

When scripture speaks of one being a Son of God or a Son of Satan, or even a Son of Abraham, it is not speaking of the flesh. Being a Son of X means that you follow the ways of X, acting in accordance with their teachings and commands, doing their will.

@RyanPierceWilliams, yeah you do not have a father? Check the ten commandments, honor your father and mother

@SoFewAgainstSoMany see John 8:39-47

@user57467, yeah like how I wondered how the devil can have an offspring or bring forth one  or how the devil can walk over his belly for the rest of his life , wait the devil is eternal so that serpent was a creature

As far as I know most commentators have always thought the story clearly indicates that the Devil tempted Eve by possessing a literal snake.  That the curse on the snake was then both literal on the animal that previously did not crawl on its belly and spiritual on the Devil.
The literal descendants of the snake would literally bite the heel of humanity. Even more importantly the descendants of the spiritual seed of Eve, a single seed, Christ, would spiritually crush the head of the Devil. In addition Christ the seed includes his whole body, that is all believers in the promised seed.  This also means spiritually all those not of Christ, are included in the body of men having enmity against the body of Christ being children of the Devil spiritually.
There can be different nuances along these lines by different commentators but most I have read if not all consider the snake to be a literal animal. On the other hand none consider it to be only an animal and it would be ridiculous to think that a mere animal could bring the downfall of all of humanity into sin and death.

This lacks any substantiation and is only anecdotal.

I see this idea a little bit like type/antitype. We have the physical world example ij the snake talking with Eve (type) as a manifestation of Satan (antitype). Satan possessed the snake in the garden and so I think God was talking to Satan when he spoke to the snake.
